# Knowing what RDFA vocabulary to use

Tags: semantic-web, semantic-markup, rdfa

How do we know which vocabulary/namespace to use to describe data with RDFa?

I have seen a lot of examples that use `xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"` or `xmlns:sioc="http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#"` then there is [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ldl0m-5zLz4) that uses FOAF vocabulary.

This is all pretty confusing and I am not sure what these vocabularies mean or what is best to use for the data I am describing. Is there some trick I am missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The simplest thing is to check if [schema.org](http://schema.org/) covers your needs. Schema.org is backed by Google and the other major search engines and generally pretty awesome.

If it doesn't suit your needs, then enter a few of the terms you need into a vocabulary search engine. My recommendation is [LOV](http://lov.okfn.org/dataset/lov/search/).

Another option is to just ask the community about the best vocabularies for the specific domain you need to represent. A good place is [answers.semanticweb.com](http://answers.semanticweb.com/), which is like StackOverflow but with more RDF experts hanging out.

Comment: The LOV link is dead

Answer (score 16):

There are *many* vocabularies. And you could create your own, too, of course (but you probably shouldn’t before you checked possible alternatives).

You’d have to look for vocabularies for your specific needs, for example

- by browsing and searching on http://lov.okfn.org/dataset/lov/ (they collect and index open vocabularies),
- on W3C’s [RDFa Core Initial Context](http://www.w3.org/2011/rdfa-context/rdfa-1.1) (it lists vocabularies that have pre-defined prefixes for use with RDFa), or
- by browsing through http://prefix.cc/ (it’s a lookup for typically used namespaces, but you might get an overview by that).

After some time you get to know the big/broad ones: [Schema.org](http://schema.org/), [Dublin Core](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dublin_Core), [FOAF](http://www.foaf-project.org/), [RSS](http://web.resource.org/rss/1.0/), [SKOS](http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/), [SIOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantically-Interlinked_Online_Communities), [vCard](http://www.w3.org/TR/vcard-rdf/), [DOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOAP), [Open Graph](http://ogp.me/), [Ontology for Media Resources](http://www.w3.org/TR/mediaont-10/), [GoodRelations](http://goodrelations-vocabulary.org/), [DBpedia Ontology](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Ontology), ….

Answer (score 4):

Things have changed quite a bit since that video was posted. First, like Richard said, you should check if schema.org fits your needs. Personally when I need to describe something that's not covered on schema.org, I check LOV as well. If, and only if I can't find anything in LOV, I will then consider creating a new type or property. A quick way to do this is to use http://open.vocab.org/

A newer version of RDFa was published since that video was released: RDFa 1.1 and RDFa Lite. If you want to use schema.org only, I'd recommend to check http://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-lite/

Answer (score 1):

Vocabularies are usually domain specific. The xmlns line is deprecated. The RDFa profile at http://www.w3.org/profile/rdfa-1.1  lists the vocabularies available as part of initial context. Sometimes vocabularies may overlap in the context of your data. Analogous to solving math prb by either Algebraic or Geometric or other technique, mixing up vocabularies is fine. Equal terms can be found using http://sameas.org/ For addressing your consumer base's favoritism amongst vocab recognition, skos:closeMatch and skos:exactMatch may be used, eg. "gr:Brand skos:closeMatch owl:Thing" with any terms you please. Prefix attribute can be used with vocabularies besides those covered by initial context like: prefix="fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# vocab2: path2 ..." For cross-cutting concern across different domain vocabularies such as customizing presentation in search results microdata using schema.org guidelines should be beneficial. However, as this has nothing to do with specialization in any peculiar domain, prefixes are unavailable in this syntax. RDFa vocab have been helpful in such specific domain contexts that content seems to appeal further to participative audience while microdata targets those who've lost their way. For tasks that are too simple to merit full-fledged vocab, but have semantic implications, try http://microformats.org/ Interchanging usage of REST profile URIs for vocabs amongst the 3 syntaxes is valid, but useless owing to lack of affordable manpower to implement alternative support for the vocabs on the Web scale. How & why schema.org vocab merited separate microdata syntax of its own is discussed by Google employee Ian Hickson a. k. a. Hixie- the editor of WHATWG HTML5 draft at http://logbot.glob.com.au/?c=freenode%23whatwg&s=28+Nov+2012&e=28+Nov+2012#c747855 or http://krijnhoetmer.nl/irc-logs/whatwg/20121128#l-1122 If only Google had smart enough employees to implement parser for 1 syntax whose WG included its own employee also, then RDFa Lite inside RDFa would have been another course like Core Java within Java, & no need of separate microdata named mocking rip-off, but alas- our's is an imperfect world!

Comment: I learnt awhole lot more after that answer. Update: To recognize correct vocab, 1. identify aspects of use-case. 2. Co-relate them to get domain-specific aspects. For these mostly an easy-to-find vocab is present. 3. Remaining aspects are usually cross-cutting concerns through other domains, such as persistence using cookies or online search using google and yahoo. If there's compulsion to use vocab, there's always schema.org with obscure properties like text and types as generic as thing and webpage that should be presumed anyhow and goes anyplace as well.