# RDF Vocabulary and predicates

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, rdfs

I am trying to convert some data to RDF format.
I am able to create the basic ontologies using the dc and foaf types.
The problem is that for more complex ontologies I need some more specific predicates.
I am looking for some more specific vocabularies but I am not sure about what a vocabulary means.It is just a URI (maybe some website) with information on terms I want to use or it must be written in RDF format?
An example:
Can I use the IMDB terminology? 
e.g http://www.imdb.com/glossary/C

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't use external URIs for RDF predicates that are not part of a vocabulary (defined by the domain owner).

Why? Well, because there is no meaning defined, you could use such an URI in a certain way, while another one might use it for something else. These triples wouldn't be "compatible" in any way. You could not re-use the data, others couldn't make sense out of it etc.

Another problem: because these URIs are not under your control and the domain owner hasn't (yet) defined a vocabulary, things could change. It could be possible that the owner decides to use this URI for a vocabulary in the future, and this probably wouldn't match your "definition" → incompatible.

However, of course you can use every URI for RDF subjects and/or RDF objects.

If you need a certain RDF predicate, [look for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12098901/1591669) published RDF vocabularies/ontologies and use their URIs. If you don't find anything, you could ask for suitable vocabularies here on Stack Overflow. And if there doesn't seem to be a vocabulary you could use, create your own (under your own domain).