# How to describe resources with dcterms or other schemas?

Tags: schema, rdf, semantic-web

I'm trying to describe some resources about books, already did:

Author: dcterms:creator;

Title: dcterms:title;

Location: dcterms:location

This was the easy ones, but i've some thigs that are not in dcterms list. Where can I find other schemas to describe it ? Can you show me examples, even how to create my own schema?

Eg. Homepage; keywords; goal

Comment: This question is about RDFa, but most suggestions should apply to other RDF formats, too, as it’s about vocabularies, not syntaxes: [Knowing what RDFA vocabulary to use](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12095945/1591669)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to search for appropriate vocabularies (or: ontologies/schemas). [There are *many* vocabularies.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12098901/1591669)

You could use http://prefix.cc/ to learn about some of them.

For books, have a look at (these are just some suggestions so that you see some examples of what is out there):

- [Dublin Core](http://dublincore.org/documents/dcmi-terms/) (as you already know)
- [FOAF (Friend of a Friend)](http://www.foaf-project.org/) (e.g., for authors and topics)
- [schema.org](http://schema.org/) (e.g., [Book](http://schema.org/Book) and [Person](http://schema.org/Person))
- [The Bibliographic Ontology](http://bibliontology.com/)

  > provides main concepts and properties for describing citations and bibliographic references (i.e. quotes, books, articles, etc) on the Semantic Web.
- [Ontology for Media Resources](http://www.w3.org/TR/mediaont-10/)

  > a core set of metadata properties for media resources
- [SPAR (Semantic Publishing and Referencing Ontologies)](http://purl.org/spar/)

  > a suite of orthogonal and complementary ontology modules for creating comprehensive machine-readable RDF metadata for all aspects of semantic publishing and referencing

You could create your own vocabulary (but you should only do this if there is no appropriate vocabulary). It’s as simple as defining meanings for [URIs under your control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14920906/1591669). If you intend to publish this vocabulary, so that other people can use it, too, have a look at [RDFS](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/) (which is a vocabulary to describe vocabularies). See also:

- RDF Primer: [Defining RDF Vocabularies: RDF Schema](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-primer/#rdfschema)
- RDFa Primer: [Custom Vocabularies](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-primer/#custom-vocabularies)
- [Best Practice Recipes for Publishing RDF Vocabularies](http://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-vocab-pub/)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you have a look at [schema.org](http://schema.org/). You will find all the information you need to annotate resources related to [books](http://schema.org/Book) among other things, and even documentation explaining how to extend your vocabulary if needed.