# Schema.org usage of WPHeader (or how to add structured data to ‘Hero’ images

Tags: semantic-web, schema.org

This question is related to this question: [Uniform way to add multiple descriptive properties in Schema.org](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47887409/5021680)

Recently I found this code on [HTML5 & Schema.org - Structured Microdata for SEO](https://ludwig.im/en/projects/html5-and-schema.org-seo-best-practices-for-microdata), along with the statement that the Schema.org `WPHeader` type **is a `WebPageElement` that can include markup from `CreativeWork` as well as `Thing`**:

```html
<header role="banner" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="A name">
    <meta itemprop="description" content="A description text">
    <h1 itemprop="headline">A headline text</h1>
    <img itemprop="image" src="image.jpg">
</header>
```

If the above statement and usage of `WPHeader` is correct, I wonder if the code below whould make sense in terms of structured data for the sematic web. The reason behind my question is that I am looking for a solution in which I can use a banner/hero image for webpages presenting an `Event` (or other) type with typical `CreativeWork` properties such as `headine`, `creator` etc.

```html
    <article>
         <!-- Banner/hero image section for Event-->
         <header class="my_hero_class" role="banner" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader">
            <meta itemprop="name" content="My Event">
            <meta itemprop="description" content="Description of My Event">
            <meta itemprop="keywords" content="keyword1, keyword2, keyword3">
            <h1 itemprop="headline">A headline text</h1>
            <p itemprop="alternateHeadline">Another headline text<p>
            <p itemprop="creator">Artist name<p>
            <img itemprop="image" src="hero_image.jpg">
        </header>
        <!-- Event section -->
        <section class="my_event_class" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
           <h2 itemprop="name">Name of My Event</h2>
           <p itemprop="description">Description of My Event</p>
           <p itemprop="text">Text about My Event</p>
           <p itemprop="startDate" content="2016-04-21T20:00">Thu, 04/21/16 8:00 p.m.</p>
<meta itemprop="startDate" content="2016-04-21T20:00">
           <img itemprop="image" src="poster.jpg">
        </section>
        <!-- Event Artist section --> 
        <section class="my_person_class" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
           <h2 itemprop="name">Name of Artist</h2>
           <p itemprop="description">Description of of Artist</p>
           <p itemprop="text">Text about of Artist</p>
           <img itemprop="image" src="artist.jpg">
        </section>
    </article>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `WPHeader`

The [`WPHeader`](http://schema.org/WPHeader) type is for the header of a page (i.e., `WebPage`).

If you add properties to `WPHeader`, these properties describe the header (!), not the page.

So, for example, the `name` might be "Header", the `image` might be a screenshot of the header etc. This is of course typically not useful to have on a page, and typically not useful to provide as structured data, so [my recommendation is not to use them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27867175/1591669).

#### `WebPage`

It seems to me that the [`WebPage`](http://schema.org/WebPage) type is what you want. Its `name` is the name of the page, its `description` is the description of the page etc.

If the page is about a single entity (e.g., an `Event`), then you could use the more specific [`ItemPage`](http://schema.org/ItemPage) type. With the [`mainEntity`](http://schema.org/mainEntity) property, you can specify the primary entity of that page.

The `ItemPage` might share some property values with the `Event` (e.g., the `description` might be the same), but there might also be slight differences (e.g., the `name` of the `WebPage` might contain the site name in addition).

```html
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemPage">

  <!-- properties about the event page -->

  <article itemprop="mainEntity" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
    <!-- properties about the event -->
  </article>

  <!-- properties about the event page -->

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Unor. Great explanation. My main concern remains, however: what would be a reasonable ‘type’ and set of ‘properties’ for a ‘Hero’ image and its text overlays?

Comment: I also wonder if the statement that a WPHeader type may have properties from Thing and CreativeWork, is correct; this because in that case I thought a header would be suitable to “render” as Hero, if users of my application whish to present ‘header’ information in such a way.

Comment: @iep: You can use all properties that are listed in the table on a type’s page. The table has sub-headings pointing out where the properties are defined. In case of `WPHeader` you can see that the properties come from `WebPageElement`, `CreativeWork`, and `Thing`. -- In other words: You can use properties from the type itself as well as from all of its parent types.

Comment: @iep: If you really want to provide data about the hero image (and not about the content presented by this image), then `WPHeader` is the right type (assuming that it’s the hero image of the web page). What you convey is: *This web page (`WebPage`) has this header (`WPHeader`), and this image (`ImageObject`) is part of the header (`image`/`hasPart`).* -- I don’t see how this would be interesting for consumers of your structured data, but that would be the way to specify it.

Comment: This seems to be what I want to convey, because how you describe it, is exactly how the situation is (in my application case). If this is not interesting for consumers, would it **harm** consumers??? In my application the HTML is rendered based on sdo schema’s (which are used to catalogue/catagorize authors, artists, publications and events). The ‘Hero’ image is typically a presentation thing, not semantic (it seems to be used often to beautify only). But, the textoverlays *might* contain meaningful content such as names, dates or authors.

Comment: @iep: No harm (if used correctly). But, to be clear, the textoverlay content (e.g., the author name) should *not* be specified in properties of `WPHeader` (if you’d use `author`, you would specify the author of the `WPHeader`, not the author of the `WebPage`).

Comment: Ok, glad you are so clear about this point. So, if one wants to add a textoverlay to a Hero image (which is part of *WPHeader*) and such a text actually is a text describing the *author* of a *CreativeWork* which the *WebPage* is about (the  *mainEntity*), this text should not have any property if it appears in the *WPHeader*, but **the same text** could appear again as a property (*author*) of the *CreativeWork*? Such a scenario would work for my application case.

Comment: @iep: Yes. The text can still be part of the HTML element which has the `itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader", but don’t mark it up with `itemprop` attributes inside, so Microdata will ignore it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this very useful discussion