# How do I make my raw scientific data useful to the semantic web?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, linked-data

I have a large set of raw structured datasets in CSV and HDF5 format. I would usually upload these to a web server as they are, but what steps are required to incorporate this data to the semantic web?

Comment: This is really too broad for the StackOverflow format, I think. "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format." If you've got a specific problem, "Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs."   However, this _is_ a good question, and I think it might be a better fit on http://answers.semanticweb.com.

Answer (score 4):

Tim Berners-Lee defined the [5 stars of Linked Open Data](http://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/LinkedData.html).

Assuming that your data is licensed under an open license, your data would have 3 stars currently.

To get 4 stars, you need to use

> open standards from W3C (RDF and SPARQL) to identify things, so that people can point at your stuff

This could mean, for example:

**Use RDF** (in the form of a [serialization format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework#Serialization_formats) of your choice) and **define URIs** for your entities so that you and other people can make statements about them. If you like, you could also offer a **SPARQL endpoint** so that other people can query your data on your server.

As a first and less complex step, you could start with publishing RDF metadata *about* your data, e.g., about its license, authors, general topic, creation date etc. There are [many vocabularies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12098901/1591669) you could use.

Comment: Not a recommendation (I don’t know them), but maybe useful: [Scholarly HTML](http://scholarlyhtml.org/), [Semantic Science](http://code.google.com/p/semanticscience/).