# Correct URL for itemtype product

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

I've been reading [on Google about microdata for products](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/146750) and they show the `itemtype` url as:

```
itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Product"
```

Yet when I look at, for example, Ebay, they use:

```
itemtype="http://schema.org/Product"
```

Is one correct and one not? Or do they both serve the same purpose?

There's not as much data out there as I would have thought...Is this still in it's infancy or just not really catching on?

I understand this is essentially two questions but they are related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both serve the same purpose but schema.org is becoming the standard

The data-vocabulary.org is the older version and on it's site it tells you to use schema.org

[From www.data-vocabulary.org:](http://www.data-vocabulary.org/)

> Since June 2011, several major search engines have been collaborating on a new common data vocabulary called schema.org.
>
> The schema.org vocabulary can be used with both Microdata or RDFa 1.1 Lite syntax

Answer (score 1):

Schema.org and Data-Vocabulary.org are different *vocabularies*.

Their respective `Product` types are not identical:

- Schema.org defines it as "Any offered product or service" while Data-Vocabulary.org says it "represents a product" (not mentioning services; however, its RDF/XML version [does](http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/rdf.xml)).
- Data-Vocabulary.org defines only 8 properties for this type, while Schema.org has more than 30. For example, you can’t specify the manufacturer with Data-Vocabulary.org (while it’s possible with Schema.org’s [`manufacturer` property](http://schema.org/manufacturer)).

There is no "correct" or "wrong" type. While the Data-Vocabulary.org vocabulary is inactive and probably no longer subject to evolution, you can still use it. However, if you have no specific reason to use it (where a reason could be a specific consumers that interprets this markup), go with Schema.org.

You could also use both ([or even more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12098901/1591669)) vocabularies for the same content.

Microdata is limited in that regard, so you could only use Schema.org’s [`additionalType` property](http://schema.org/additionalType) for this:

```html
<div itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <link itemprop="additionalType" href="http://data-vocabulary.org/Product">
  <!-- you may only use properties from Schema.org; for properties from other vocabularies, you’d have to use absolute URIs -->
</div>
```

But with RDFa 1.1 (Lite), you have the full power of multi-vocabulary use:

```html
<div typeof="schema:Product v:Product">
  <!-- you may use any property, no matter from which vocabulary -->
</div>
```

(`schema:` and `v:` are [pre-defined prefixes](http://www.w3.org/2011/rdfa-context/rdfa-1.1) for Schema.org and Data-Vocabulary.org.)