# Are foaf:Person and schema.org/Person compatible with each other? or better stick with one of them?

Tags: semantic-web, schema.org, turtle-rdf, foaf

1. schema.org is better for SEO
2. From https://lov.linkeddata.es/dataset/lov/ it seems FOAF has more adoption?

I have used the ontology:

```
@prefix dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> .
@prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .
@prefix gr: <http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#> .
```

GoodRelations is worry free as it is mostly compatible with schema.org, but what about the other two? i.e.

1. dcterms:creator vs https://schema.org/creator
2. foaf:Person vs https://schema.org/Person

Comment: Regarding SEO: What you are probably referring to are the search result features search engines offer based on Schema.org, right? Note that search engines typically only support certain syntaxes: JSON-LD, Microdata, RDFa, but not Turtle. (See also: [Schema.org and SEO](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/108333/17633))

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I think I can find converters to transform Turtle to all other formats, but if I defined it with other ontologies, I can't automatically convert it to the schema.org definitions, so should I change everything to use shema.org to save me trouble later on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple vocabularies/ontologies to describe the same entity.

If a consumer (like a search engine) only recognizes terms from a specific vocabulary (like Schema.org), it will simply ignore the terms from the other vocabularies (like FOAF).

So, for an entity that represents a person, you could use the types [`schema:Person`](https://schema.org/Person), [`foaf:Person`](http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/#term_Person) and/or [`dcterms:Agent`](http://dublincore.org/documents/dcmi-terms/#terms-Agent). And for a book this person wrote, you could use the properties [`schema:creator`](https://schema.org/creator), [`foaf:maker`](http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/#term_maker), and/or [`dcterms:creator`](http://dublincore.org/documents/dcmi-terms/#terms-creator).

If your primary motivation is SEO (instead of Linked Data), [I would recommend](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49255326/1591669) to use the vocabulary Schema.org as far as possible, and other vocabularies in addition (at least where Schema.org is lacking, or, if you prefer, wherever it’s possible).

Comment: So I can re-define original `foaf:homepage <https://github.com/miranda-zhang>`  with https://schema.org/url, and keep both, so they can all be recognized? Or do I need to delete the other one if I decided to use schema.org?

Comment: @Miranda: Pointing you to the first two sentences in my answer ;-) You can add as many triples as you want. There is no reason to assume that consumers would have a problem with triples they don’t need for the job they have.